# Tuning in TV to Raspberry Pi output. On a channel, not on HDMI. Impossible?

Tags: hdmi, raspberry-pi, tv

For highly esoteric reasons, in fact almost embarrassing, I would like to connect my Raspberry Pi to a normal "tuner" *CHANNEL* on my ("standard" five year old) LCD TV.

*Of course I realise that this should normally be accomplished with HDMI and setting the TV source to (say) HDMI1 to view the output.*

But can anyone suggest a solution whereby I can turn my TV to (say) "channel 5" and have that channel display the Pi's output?

I am prepared for this to be impossible, but wanted to rule out the possibility by consulting the great and the good here.

PS - If you solve it, I will tell you why I want to do it (maybe!). It involves Star Trek.

Comment: You need to convert the HDMI signal to an RF TV signal.  Only recently (within past year) has an ATSC modulator become available for consumer use.  You would probably need a DVB-T modulator.

Comment: ...this is starting to sound "impossible" on a financial basis! :( Thanks so much for info. Can anyone think out of the box?! :)

Comment: What on earth is the downvote for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this product should do it

http://www.hdtvsupply.com/hdmi-to-coax-adaptor.html

Comment: That will only output a standard definition (i.e. not HD quality) video signal.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks very much :) In this case SD might do the trick, but would love to hear any other suggestions! But wow! That thing's $150!